# Identify arthropod with many legs in Mumbai

Tags: species-identification, zoology, invertebrates, arthropod

Can someone please identify this ~5 cm long arthropod? I've been finding one of these every 2-3 days inside my apartment ever since rainy season started here in Mumbai (June).

The bulb portion is its head. The arthropod is capable of climbing walls.

Thanks.

[image]

Video of the worm (shot while brooming the floor. Hence the dirt)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB16p.jpg

By the way, I've seen it 6 times in the last 2-3 weeks. Except once when I saw it on the bathroom floor, all other instances were during night time. So perhaps this is some sort of a nocturnal creature?

Comment: It looks like a centipede. Can you confirm how does it move?

Comment: I've edited my post with a video link. Please check.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! In the future please [edit] your post to include all essential information (e.g. size in this case) — comments are ephemeral and so should not be used to covey information important for understanding or answering the question. Also note that this is almost certainly a millipede rather than a worm. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure It's a millipede from the Julida order, that includes 750 species distributed in the northern hemisphere.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julida
[image: Unidentified Parajulidae]